# How to fix "Error: Could not find or load main class ”-Djava.library.path=.usr.local.hadoop.lib” while installing hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.9.2 on Ubuntu.

I have set same path to JAVA_HOME in ~/.bashrc and env.sh files.Two separate directories for data node and name node are created under hadoop_store with the right path.The java version is "java-11-openjdk-amd64".
I am still facing an error while formating the namenode in the hadoop file system. Please help me in resolving it.

The link to the page whose instrutions I have been following.
https://www.digitalvidya.com/blog/install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-and-run-your-first-mapreduce-program/

This is the error:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hadoop namenode -format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Error: Could not find or load main class ”-Djava.library.path=.usr.local.hadoop.lib”
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ”-Djava.library.path=.usr.local.hadoop.lib”
```

Answer (score 10):

check your ~/.bashrc

if you add line

`export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"`

make sure the "" is correct

Comment: can you please review my issue? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69271700/hdfs-namemode-command-in-bash-is-returning-error]

Answer (score 2):

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"

changed to this

export HADOOP_OPTS='-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native'

and it worked and am done with the installation opened it in browser.

Answer (score -2):

My case was that I put a space between "-D" and "java", which caused the failure
Should be as below

```
~/.bashrc file should be: export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

but in my case i had this

```
~/.bashrc file:  export HADOOP_OPTS="-D java.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```